# Is there a way to trigger the Windows 10 Mobile upgrade on an eligible phone

Tags: update, windows-10-mobile, lumia-640-xl

I downloaded the [upgrade advisor app](http://aka.ms/W10MUpgradeAdvisor) on my Lumia 640XL, which is not carrier locked, and checked for the Windows 10 upgrade, and it showed that my device is eligible for the update. But its been a week now since the upgrade was released, and the same message still shows.

[image: screenshot of message thats showing in upgrade advisor app]

I'm becoming a bit impatient, and would like to get the upgrade right away. 
Is there a way to trigger the update to start downloading for my phone.

PS: I don't wish to join the Preview program.

Comment: Seems you are living in a country where updates needs to approved by network operators. You will have to wait till your operator allows the windows 10 upgrade. It will be better if you could talk to your operator.

Comment: But, i even removed my SIM card, and used my Wi-Fi network to try and upgrade, but still, all the same

Comment: The update needs to be approved by the network operators in certain countries even it is distributed by Microsoft. Is your phone carrier locked?

Comment: That's the point I was trying to express. No, its not carrier locked

Comment: That's strange. Unlocked Lumia phones are receiving updates. I'm sorry but I cannot be of more help.

Answer (score 6):

If your phone is eligible for the Windows 10 Mobile update and you're waiting for the carrier approval, you can use the [Windows Insider app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows-insider/9wzdncrfjbhk) to update your phone and then switch back to the production ring once you have installed Windows 10.

You will get the same version and firmware as with the Upgrade Advisor app.

Be advised that problems during the Update may not be covered by your warranty, though you should always be able to go back to 8.1 using the [Windows Devices Recovery Tool](http://bitly.com/WDRTool).

Comment: Are you sure I will get the same version as the latest official update. I mean, it's obvious the insider app has the latest beta release of Windows 10 Mobile , but it might not be the stable version that is currently being dispatched as the Windows 10 Mobile Official release...

Comment: With the Insider App you can upgrade to build 10586.164, which is the official one. when you're done just join the production ring and you'll only get further official updates.

Comment: Okay, but is it an advisable move, and won't it cause problems for me after the installation??

Comment: The odds of running into troubles are the same as with the Upgrade Advisor app. Be prepared to do a hard reset after upgrading to W10M, regardless of which way you go.